# remove string array on key press c# xna

Tags: c#, arrays, xna

Hi I was wondering how to go about removing a string array from the screen, however I do not want the array cleared permanently as it will be reused later. For example, I have an array of 6 strings (player one, player two...). When enter is pressed another string array is outputted (confirm player, cancel player).

When the user presses enter when 'cancel player' is highlighted I want this second string removed leaving only the original six options. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.Length - 2; i++)
        {



            if (i == selectedIndex)
                tint = highlight;



            else
                tint = normal;
            spriteBatch.DrawString(
                spriteFont,
                menuItems[i],
                location,
                tint);
            location.Y += spriteFont.LineSpacing + 5;
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the situation correctly, you already know which is the selected item, right? Now you want to know if a key from the keyboard is pressed while one specific option is highlighted?

Answer (score 0):

Do this when the second menu list is opened

```
String[] bkup = menuItems;
```

Put when when cancel player is selected

```
if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.enter)) //When enter is pressed
{
    menuItems = bkup; //Sets menuItems back
}
```

I'm not too sure what the question is, but I think this is what you want. When the second menu is opened, the current array is copied into a new variable, a "backup" of the first menu, and when enter is pressed and the close selection is selected, it will replace `menuItems` with `bkup`, the first array.